# What does this error message mean: Not enough data to create this user

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have this WP error message instead of user_id : Not enough data to create this user. I am trying to create a new user programmatically. This code works on another project I worked on, but returns an error on the current one am working on.

the code

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```

Comment: Are you passing $username, $password, $email  ?

Comment: yes, I am passing them.

Comment: The error message is "not enough data to create this user"

Answer (score 0):

It means that the $user does not return the user object, but false which means wp_create_user is probably returning an error object.

Check the wp_create_user arguments!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was WP Cerber Plugin. Disabled it and now everything works.